# Angular HttpClient get() method blocked by current query parameters

Tags: angular

I'm running into an issue where if my current url has query parameters, the first time I fire a get() request from the HttpClient, it removes the query parameters from the URL and doesn't make the request.

Then if I fire it again afterward, it works. Anyone have any idea what's going here?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please add some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP Interceptor was causing issues. Solved.